# Handling concurrency without additional column in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Is it somehow possible to handle concurrency in `Entity Framework` without adding an additional column like described in this [MSDN-article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399228.aspx)?
There are only solutions described where i have to change the database structure, but it is not possible to change the Database i am working with, so i need another possibility.

**EDIT:**
The conflicts should be handled optimistic. There are several (hundreds) of tables, so what i am looking for is a more general solution, not specific to one table.

Comment: How do you want to handle conflicts? And what columns are available?

Comment: You will need to have some sort of a column that you can be sure will change on every update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this: [Handling Concurrency with the Entity Framework](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

> Configure the Entity Framework to include the original values of every
>   column in the table in the Where clause of `Update` and `Delete` commands
>
> If you do want to implement this approach to concurrency, you have to
>   mark all non-primary-key properties in the entity you want to track
>   concurrency for by adding the `ConcurrencyCheck` attribute to them